# Sorting woocommerce shop (fooevents) category by title filter

Tags: sorting, woocommerce, filter, categories, title

I have added the following code in a snippet
I use the fooevents plugin for the events.

https://chromlack.eu/shop/ we want the training events also displayed there.

I have a seperate page for the training classes https://chromlack.eu/training/ and I can sort because I am only displaying the 'training' category

Anyone can help me with it, I would appreciate it:

Snippet:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args' );

function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
    $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? wc_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters(     'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );
    if ( 'random_list' == $orderby_value ) {
      $args['orderby'] = 'title';
      $args['order'] = 'DESC';
      $args['meta_key'] = '';
    }
    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );


function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $sortby ) {
$product_categories = array('training'); // <== HERE define your product category

    // Only for defined product category archive page
    if( ! is_product_category($product_categories) ) return $sortby;

    $sortby['random_list'] = 'title';
    return $sortby;
}
```

The filter code I have is not working.  Woocommerce support only could help to a limit